# How do I get the caller(s) of a method without running this system (written in JAVA)

Tags: java, eclipse

In java, How can I get the caller(s) of a method without running this system. 
My purpose is to find the callers of some methods (around 150 methods) and want to get
the name of all callers of each method. Is it possible to do that?

Is there possible way to do it ( that is not to use call hierarchy or reference in Eclipse because I need to find the callers of many methods and record it to my excel file.)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: so sorry. I haven't found the answer I like because I didn't give the detail of the question enough. So I have updated the question

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can't always know whether the method is called, since there can be callers outside of your code, for instance a rules engine can be calling your method while your code would never be calling the method and you would just be able to find out that the method was called by putting a break point and running debugging under the correct conditions...

Answer (score 17):

In Eclipse, you can do this by right-clicking the method, and choosing "Open Call Hierarchy".

Answer (score 2):

Also, in Eclipse, you can do this by right-clicking the method, and choosing "**references**" -> "XXX"

Answer (score 2):

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719634/how-do-i-get-the-callers-of-a-method-without-running-this-system-written-in-ja/4719641#4719641) mentioned, this is called the Call Hierarchy. You can access it from the right-click menu, or just use the keyboard shortcut: put your cursor on the method name, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you can do this by right-clicking the method, and choosing "Open Call Hierarchy".

See 5 options given on right side top of that panel (Refresh) (Cancel Current Search) (Show Caller Hierarchy) (Show Callee Hierarchy) (Show History List)

For You the 3rd option will work..

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you can right click on the method name and click 'Open Call Hierarchy'. Another panel opens and select  'Open caller hierarchy'

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but based on your updated question and comment, you want to retrieve the names of all callers of *multiple* methods in one go (and not have to do the same thing, i.e. open Call Hierarchy, 150 times) and end up with something in a format you can use in a spreadsheet.

Here's how to do that with Eclipse for anyone facing the same issue (as I did recently):

1. **Get all the methods whose callers you're interested in into the same view.** If they're all in the same class, the *Outline* view will do, otherwise do a search and get all your methods to show in the *Search* results view - you can specify all sorts of interesting criteria in there, in your case you might want to search for methods in selected resources (select your classes in the *Package Explorer* first).
   [image: Eclipse search dialog]
2. **Select all the methods whose callers you're interested in in that view.** Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click to multi-select, or do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to *Select all* and then de-select the ones you don't want with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click.
3. **Open the *Call Hierarchy* on all those methods.** Either drag those selected methods onto the *Call Hierarchy* view, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, or use the context menu. This will show *all* the callers of *all* those methods. (If you want to dive deeper, expand as required to retrieve callers of callers, etc.)
4. **Select all in the *Call Hierarchy* view.** Just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> while the view has focus.
5. **Copy the methods' qualified names to the clipboard.** There's no keyboard shortcut for this by default, but you can right-click on the selected files and select *Copy Qualified Name*. You'll end up with a bunch of lines of the format `<package name>.<class name>.<method name>()`.
6. **Paste into your favourite text editor or spreadsheet and manipulate as required.**

Tested in Eclipse neon.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans, right click on the method and go to "find usages". Alternatively, click on the method name and then hit alt+F7.

EDIT: Oops, just seen this is tagged for eclipse and not netbeans. Still, I'll leave it here in case it's useful.